# Null pointer in button in layout-large-land

Tags: android, xml, nullpointerexception, android-fragmentactivity, landscape

I have a strange problem i have created a xml in layout-large-land and in that i have placed some buttons 
and i have written a activity for that xml file and i check whether it is landscape in a large screen and then 
i wrote click to the button but unfortunately it says null pointer exception i dont understand what am i doing wrong , i am checking with my samsung Tab3

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/topPick"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dip" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dip" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dip" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dip" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my activity

```
  import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    Button topPick;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (isTablet(MainActivity.this)) {
            // tablet
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            topPick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.topPick);

            topPick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yyyyyyy", 2000)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        } else {
            // phone
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }
    }

    public boolean isTablet(Context context) {
        boolean xlarge = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == 4);
        boolean large = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE);
        return (xlarge || large);
    }

}
```

Here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.screentest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.screentest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my logcat

```
06-21 15:41:44.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30469): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 15:41:44.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30469): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.screentest/com.example.screentest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 15:41:44.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30469):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
06-21 15:41:44.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30469):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
06-21 15:41:44.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30469):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:154)
06-21 15:41:44.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30469):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
06-21 15:41:44.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30469):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-21 15:41:44.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30469):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-21 15:41:44.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30469):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
06-21 15:41:44.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30469):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 15:41:44.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30469):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-21 15:41:44.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30469):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
06-21 15:41:44.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30469):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
06-21 15:41:44.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30469):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-21 15:41:44.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30469): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 15:41:44.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30469):  at com.example.screentest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
06-21 15:41:44.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30469):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5255)
06-21 15:41:44.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30469):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
06-21 15:41:44.900: E/AndroidRuntime(30469):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2213)
```

Comment: show logcat output...

Comment: Post your Logcat error

Comment: **Read** the logcat. It comes with a line number and much more. That shows you what is null and where. Look at that line and think about why it was null when you tried to use it. Make sure it isn't null. Problem solved. It looks like this: `Main.java:23`, meaning line 23.

Comment: its showing null pointer on the button object, i have registered the button still its showing the same error

Comment: why these people are putting negative votes..

Comment: @George show your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @SilentKiller: Manifest posted

Comment: include this line in Application tag then check.  `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"`

Comment: @SilentKiller: null pointer still occurs

Comment: show imports of MainActivity.java

Comment: @SilentKiller imports added

Comment: Your code as well as imports are even seems ok with no issue..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56022/discussion-between-george-and-silentkiller).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working perfectly fine. See my code that i wrote in eclipse and also see the screenshot attached.

**XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/topPick"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dip" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dip" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dip" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dip" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**JAVA File**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    Button topPick;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (isTablet(MainActivity.this)) {
            // tablet
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            topPick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.topPick);
            topPick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yyyyyyy", 2000)
                            .show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            // phone
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    }

    public boolean isTablet(Context context) {
        boolean xlarge = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == 4);
        boolean large = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE);
        return (xlarge || large);
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Now just remove irrelevant parts and explain why so.

Comment: @AndroidWarrier : getView().findViewById(R.id.topPick); getview() how can we use getView method

Comment: @AndroidWarrior buddy it runs fine in emulator but gives same error with my Samsung galaxy tab 3

Comment: strange!! is that some problem of my device

Comment: @George It's working fine on my device as well mate. Maybe it's your devices issue.